# jQuery Datepicker showing selected date as my PC's date,not the server date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I pick a date from the jQuery datepicker, it is showing my Computer's date,not the server date.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery datepicker is running on the client, meaning it'll get its date from the client.

If you want to report server time, consider asking your server for its time and passing that in as a default date.

Comment: It seems that the datepicker only accepts default date, can i pass the default time too ?

Comment: @dskanth Why would you want to pass a time into the datepicker?!
Date picker is to pick date, Not time.

Comment: @Paul I am sorry to not mention, that i am using a jquery datetime picker, from this page: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 3):

See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-defaultDate

Usage:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "2010-12-31" // Put server site date here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery executes on the client browser and not the server. So you should not expect to see the server time from it.